# Painless way of consolidating files across multiple machines/OSes

Tags: file-management, data-transfer, deduplication

Just bought a NAS. So I thought I'd get all our photos, media files and pdfs consolidated, de-duplicated, de-junked and virus-checked and stick them all on it.

We have 3 laptops, one running Windows, the others OSX. We have a file server running Windows - it was the result of an earlier attempt at a networked fileserver - and a Mac Pro that is also kind of a server (previous attempts at this job have resulted in most of our stuff being on it). Also memory cards/sticks, cd backups and so on.

I would be grateful if anyone could suggest a strategy or, ideally, tool(s) I could use to solve this problem. It is probably no more than one or two terabytes of data in total, but I can imagine that going through it all manually, file-by-file may well drive me insane.

Comment: You might have to resort to a manual process. I've done deduplication from multiple sources, and frankly, the error margin is too high to let software do it for you, unless it's a very narrow field (e.g. large video files).

Answer (score 1):

its a manual process. there are limits to what things like image magic can do from scripts to try and weed out duplicates for images/videos.  if just by name is reliable then you could use a copy software to merge them all.  as for duplicate pdf's dont know of a software that would read through it and see if they are duplicates.